# how to display all row data of mysql field name

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to display all the data of mysql field but having issue display it.
What I want to do is display all the first name and last name of the members which has a membership level of 1  so if there are 20 users with membership level 1, it would display 20 first name

```
$query = "SELECT first_name, last_name FROM " . $wpdb->prefix . "ss_table WHERE membership_level = 1";
echo $query[20];
```

Comment: You didn't execute the query. You just did `$query[20]` which is wrong because `$query` is a string, not an array.

Comment: how do I execute a query?

Answer (score 0):

Your sql query is wrong, you should first check out sql sites for writing query
For fetching a single column from a table you have to use

```
select first_name from ss_table
```

but for fetching more than one column you have to append "," after every column name except after the last column

```
select first_name, last_name from ss_table
```

Comment: sorry just forgot the apostrephe on it but my problem is display it in a loop

Comment: why not use a for loop and display every value, $query[0], $query[1],....$query[20]

Comment: $query doesn't contain any values. $query[0] is "S" $query[1] is "E". It's just a string. It needs to be executed.

Comment: this might help:
`while($row_data = mysql_fetch_array($row_data))
 {
  $row_first_name = $row_data['column_first_name];
  $row_last_name = $row_data['column_last_name'];
  echo $row_first_name;
  echo $row_last_name;
}`

Answer (score -1):

You've written a query, but you need to execute it if you want to get results. Echoing $query[20] will just give you the 20th character of your query statement. Look into some docs: http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php or tutorials on how to connect to a database.

Comment: i did look but having trouble understanding it

Comment: There are endless tutorials on this that should bring some clarity. Also tons on stack overflow too.

Comment: I know , I wouldn't post a question if I had find a solution and I did look at tutorials and search stacks

Comment: Alright, well nobody is going to write the code for you. You need to attempt it yourself first. https://www.sanwebe.com/2013/03/basic-php-mysqli-usage

Comment: Im not expecting someone to code for me, I am seeking an answer not links to bunch of tutorial I have already seen

Comment: Here to help. Show us the other code you've written to connect to a database then.